# Is it posible to format a mysql decimal value output?

Tags: mysql

In MySQL I've a value stored as `decimal(11,2)` and when I make a select it returns values in the format:

```
10.00
100.00
```

Would be it posible to return this values in this format?

```
10,00
100,00
```

Comment: Whist it is *possible* (as @juergend demonstrates in [his answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10650171/623041)), I feel that such presentational matters are more appropriate in your application than the database: indeed, many languages support locale-specific formatting of this sort either intrinsically or with a mere call to some library function.

Comment: My problem was that local currency parsing functions where parsing 10.00 as 1000 when it should be 10.

Comment: In what language? Numeric types are returned by MySQL as numbers, not strings - so any such parsing would take place purely within your application code...

Comment: Yes, the problem is in the application side. It parses mysql returned values from string to number. @juergen-d solution does the job for this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
select replace(cast(100.00 as char), '.', ',')
```